# Register a new user on firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

i am new working with firebase and i am making a login and register windows for an app using firebase.

Right now the log in worked fine for me as long as i created the account from the console 
[This is what the login code looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/805nt.png)

but then if you want to create a new account you click on that button down there and it will take you to a new viewcontroller window, there i added things to fill to make a new a account and i used

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(<email: String>, password: <String>, completion: <FIRAuthResultCallback?(FIRUser?, NSError?) -> Void#>)
```

here a picture of how the code looks like
[picture of the code and the imageview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCOrX.png)

When i try to register a new user i get the doesn't work message and i really don't know why it doesn't create a new user

bonus question
when i make it work how do i make it go from that window to another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


@IBAction func signup(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let em = email.text, pass = password.text{
        FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(email.text!, password: password.text!) {(user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            else {
                print("User signed in!")

                self.ref.child("data/users").updateChildValues(["\(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)":["Username":self.username.text!]])

                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("home", sender: self)
                //At this point, the user will be taken to the next screen
            }
        } }
    else{
        print("You left email/password empty")
    }
}
```

Make sure you've installed both Firebase, FirebaseAuth and FirebaseDatabase (If you're using cocoapods, your pod should look like the one below)

```
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
```

Comment: I'm getting this 'Value of type 'RegisterViewController' has no member 'ref'. Should i put another thing on ref? sorry i am new working on this

Comment: I am getting a bit of an error tho! everytime i create a new user i get a thread 1: signal SIGABRT how could i fix this??

Even tho it does create the new account, i have to close the simulation open it again and the account exists

Comment: Haha, glad I could help. Could you please upvote and mark as the correct answer? I'd really appreciate that. For your other problem, make sure you've connected your IBOutlets and IBActions properly, with no overlaps. Just review your code, and you should be able to find the issue. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24204330/swift-thread-1-signal-sigabrt

Answer (score 0):

**swift 5**

> try my code its small & easy to understand

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class RegisterViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var emailTextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextfield: UITextField!


@IBAction func registerPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if let email = emailTextfield.text, let password = passwordTextfield.text {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in
            if let e = error {
                print(e.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                //Navigate to the ChatViewController
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "RegisterToChat", sender: self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}